# MEF - partial recomposition

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I am wondering if it is possible to change MEF behavior to have a partial recomposition. Imagine that we have loaded 3 plugins into the Plugins collection.

When a new dll is placed in the proper directory, then MEF by default will recompose all plugins.
What I would like to archive is just to add only new plugins to my collection and keep the existing instances. Is that possible somehow?

Please find the source code bellow:

```
internal class ServerPluginManager : MarshalByRefObject , IServerPluginManager
{
    private readonly string _pluginDirectory;

    public DirectoryCatalog PluginCatalog;
    public CompositionContainer CompositionContainer;
    public FileSystemWatcher PluginWatcher;

    [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true, RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IServerPlugin>> Plugins { get; set; }

    public ServerPluginManager(string pluginDirectory)
    {
        _pluginDirectory = pluginDirectory;
    }

    public bool Start()
    {
        try
        {
            PluginCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(_pluginDirectory);
            CompositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(PluginCatalog, new ConfigurationExportProvider(new FileConfigurationSource()));
            CompositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);

            string domainName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;

        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
        {

            return false;
        }

        Plugins.OnEach(plugin => plugin.Run());

        PluginWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_pluginDirectory, "*.dll")
        {
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
            IncludeSubdirectories = false,
        };
        PluginWatcher.Changed += PluginWatcherOnChanged;
        PluginWatcher.Created += PluginWatcherOnCreated;
        PluginWatcher.Deleted += PluginWatcherOnDeleted;
        PluginWatcher.Renamed += PluginWatcherOnRenamed;
        PluginWatcher.Error += PluginWatcherOnError;

        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        PluginWatcher.Changed -= PluginWatcherOnChanged;
        PluginWatcher.Created -= PluginWatcherOnCreated;
        PluginWatcher.Deleted -= PluginWatcherOnDeleted;
        PluginWatcher.Renamed -= PluginWatcherOnRenamed;
        PluginWatcher.Error -= PluginWatcherOnError;
        PluginWatcher = null;

        Plugins.OnEach(plugin => plugin.Dispose());
    }

    private void PluginWatcherOnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs fileSystemEventArgs)
    {
        PluginCatalog.Refresh();
        Plugins.Where(x => x.Value.State == PluginState.Stopped).OnEach(plugin => plugin.Run());
    }

    private void PluginWatcherOnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        PluginCatalog.Refresh();
        Plugins.OnEach(plugin => plugin.Run());
    }

    private void PluginWatcherOnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        PluginCatalog.Refresh();
        Plugins.OnEach(plugin => plugin.Run());
    }

    private void PluginWatcherOnRenamed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        PluginCatalog.Refresh();
        Plugins.OnEach(plugin => plugin.Run());
    }

    private void PluginWatcherOnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        PluginCatalog.Refresh();
        Plugins.OnEach(plugin => plugin.Run());
    }
}
```